# How to add files in tableview javafx

Tags: user-interface, javafx, tableview

I created a directory to have files saved to (specifically excel and word files). I tried adding it to a table but the only thing that shows up is an empty space that can be "clicked" on (although it doesn't do anything, yet).
I can't get the name of the excel/word files to show up in the table. It clearly is able to detect the files in the directory, just no name.
I also want to be able to click on these files in the table and have the program access them after that so I don't know if I can just use a string and add that to the table or not.

Answer (score 0):

In general, the fact the you can select a row but can't see any content means you added an empty string. Another option might be the fact that you didn't define any columns. The code below shows and example of a table that can be used. It would also help if you post your code.

```
private TableView<FileWrapper> createTable(){
    //Create a new table view which contains File instances
    TableView<FileWrapper> fileView = new TableView<FileWrapper>();

    //create the column which displays the file name - a string.
    TableColumn<FileWrapper, String> nameCol = new TableColumn<FileWrapper, String>();
    //setting the text which indicates the column name
    nameCol.setText("Name");
    //defining the the values of this column are in a method called 'nameProperty' in our File class
    //the method needs to return a ReadOnlyStringProperty which contains the value to show.
    nameCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<FileWrapper, String>("name"));

    fileView.getColumns().add(nameCol);

    //Add your files to the table...

    return fileView; //returning the table so it can be used in our scene
}

//A wrapper for files in your table
public static class FileWrapper{
    private File file;//holds the file object
    private SimpleStringProperty name;//a property for the name of the file

    FileWrapper(File file){
        name = new SimpleStringProperty();
        name.set(file.getName());

        this.file = file;
    }

    //this method returns the property of the name and is used by the table to chose the value of
    //the column using it.
    public SimpleStringProperty nameProperty(){
        return name;
    }
    public String getPath(){
        return path;
    }
}
```

So we create a table view which points to a class holding the name and `File` object of each file. Than, we create a column for the name and define that its value is from the `nameProperty` method of the class. We can than add the column to the table and add any files we want.

When I use tables to select something to be opened, I use a button and when it is pressed I get the selected row `table.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem()` and open what I need accordingly.

On another note, you might want to use `ListView` instead since it seems you need only one column so a table is useless. The code below shows an example of using a `ListView`:

```
private ListView<FileWrapper> createList(){
    //create a list for FileWrapper class 
    //this time, the value used to show stuff is the value from toString of 
    //the class
    ListView<FileWrapper> fileView = new ListView<FileWrapper>();

    //Add your files to the table...

    return fileView;//return the list so it can be used in our scene
}

//A wrapper for files in your table
public static class FileWrapper{
    private File file;//holds the file object
    private String name;//the name of the file

    FileWrapper(File file){
        name = file.getName();
        this.file = file;
    }

    public File getFile(){
        return file;
    }

    //this will be the value used by the list view and shown to the user
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

Unlike before, here we need no columns and the value shown is received from the `toString` of the class. So we define a `String` variable to hold the name and return it in the `toString` of the class.

Sorry for the long answer. Hope it helped!